# Как ускорить поиск совпадений в DOM элементе через цикл?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Есть ниже упрощенный пример, в реальности рабочий код сложнее и скорость сильно медленей.

Без прерывания цикла!

Можно ли как то его ускорить?

```js
let html = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  html += `<div class="item">${i}</div>`;
}
document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = html;

function search(e) {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'));
  let value = e.target.value.toUpperCase().trim();
  if (value) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => {
      if (item.innerText === value) {
        item.classList.add('active');
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(`Go: ${new Date().getTime() - start}ms`);
}

document.querySelector('[name="search"]').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  search(e)
});
```

```css
.content .item {
  display: none;
}

.content .item.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input name="search">
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let html = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  html += `<div class="item">${i}</div>`;
}
document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = html;

const lookup = {};
document.querySelectorAll('.content .item').forEach(i => {
  (lookup[i.textContent] || (lookup[i.textContent] = [])).push(i);
});

function search(e) {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  document.querySelectorAll('.content .item.active').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'));
  let value = e.target.value.toUpperCase().trim();
  if (value && lookup[value]) {
    lookup[value].forEach(i => i.classList.add('active'));
  }
  console.log(`Go: ${new Date().getTime() - start}ms`);
}

document.querySelector('[name="search"]').addEventListener('keyup', search);
```

```css
.content .item {
  display: none;
}
.content .item.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input name="search">
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже была мысль перевести DOM в объект и делать с начало поиск по объекту, только не понимал как связать все это. Скорость шикарная!

Comment: @Meru382 От поиска по DOM-у можно вообще избавиться, если хранить активные элементы в массиве.

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема вашего кода - два одинаковых цикла. Так как циклы повторяются, то гораздо проще вынести все условия в один цикл. А в теле этого цикла через условие проверить все необходимые данные.

```js
let html = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  html += `<div class="item">${i}</div>`;
}
document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = html;

function search(e) {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(e => {

    let value = e.target?.value?.toUpperCase()?.trim();
    if (value && e.innerText === value) {
      e.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      e.classList.remove('active');
    };

  });

  console.log(`Go: ${new Date().getTime() - start}ms`);
}

document.querySelector('[name="search"]').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  search(e)
});
```

```css
.content .item {
  display: none;
}

.content .item.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input name="search">
<div class="content"></div>
```